# Does $|x^G|$ divide the order $\langle x^G\rangle$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, $x\in G$, $x^G$ denotes the conjugacy class contained $x$, that's to say
$|x^G|=n$. My question is:
what is the relationship between $|x^G|$ and the subgroup $\langle x^G\rangle$? what's more, I want to know whether $n$ divides the order of the subgroup $\langle x^G\rangle$?

Comment: What with the non-divisibility being resolved, below, you should realise that in an abelian group $x^G=x$ but $\langle x\rangle (=\langle x^G\rangle)$ can have, well, the order of any prime dividing the order of the group, say. So I think the answer to your question is "there is nothing obvious connecting these two things". On the other hand, if you assume that $G$ is non-abelian then you might get somewhere...(you might actually have to assume $G$ is centerless...)

Comment: Since $\langle x^G\rangle$ is a $normal$ subgroup, your statement holds for any $simple$ group. (Note that a group $G$ is simple iff for every $x \in G$ it holds that $\langle x^G \rangle = G$.

Answer (score 7):

Take $G=S_3$, $x=(123)$, then $x^G=\{(123),(213)\}$, whereas $\langle x^G\rangle=\{id,(123),(213)\}$. So the answer to the divisibility question is no.

Answer (score 4):

We can define conjugacy as a [group action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) on $G$.  Formally, for any $g \in G$, we define $(g,x)=gxg^{-1}$ for all $x \in G$.  The [Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbit-stabilizer_theorem) gives a description of $|x^G|$ in terms of $|G|$ and the size of the stabilizer $G_x=\{g \in G:x=gxg^{-1}\}$ of $x$.  Specifically,
\[|x^G|=\frac{|G|}{|G_x|}.\]

From this, we can deduce that $|x^G|$ divides $|G|$.  Thus, we have that $|x^G|$ and $|\langle x^G \rangle|$ are both divisors of $|G|$.

From this observation (and the fact that $|x^G| \leq |\langle x^G \rangle|$), we can determine that if $|G|$ is a prime power, than $|x^G|$ divides $|\langle x^G \rangle|$.